# Is this site supposed to be copying our questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, support, copyright

I hope this is the right place to post this.

If you go to [this link](http://youranswers.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMM05qYVdacExuTjBZV05yWlhoamFHRnVaMlV1WTI5dEwzRjFaWE4wYVc5dWN5ODVNamcyTkM5M2FHRjBMWGRoY3kxMGFHVXRjR2hoYzJWeUxYTmxkSFJwYm1jdGQyaGxiaTF6YVhOcmJ5MTBiMjlyTFhSb1pTMTNZV3hzTFdSdmQyNHRkRzh0Wm1sdVpDMTBhR1V0WW1GcWIzSmhiaTFvYVE9PQ==) you'll see that it is [one of my questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92864/what-was-the-phaser-setting-when-sisko-took-the-wall-down-to-find-the-bajoran-hi), with comments, and answers here on Sci-Fi/Fantasy Stack Exchange. I'm not sure if this is a copyright violation or if it's just a companion site. I wanted to bring it to everyone's attention just in case.

I hope I posted this in the right place and did the right thing. Thanks

EDIT/UPDATE (6/25/15-6 days after OP): Just to update, the entire site youranswers.info has been taken down. One of the commenters below (trejder) pointed it out and I checked it to make sure. The action I took when I realized this site was scraping and reposting our data was to post in both metas, send the info to the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, and I also filed a complaint with Googles scraping division. Just thought everyone should know that it worked and the site is down.

Comment: It's lacking proper attribution, so it's a copyright violation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I posted it here, on meta, and put it in the contacts. I also notified Googles scraping complaint form. It's a site that's basically scraping the data from here in real time, reposting it as if it's their own information, and then selling advertising through pop ups. Every time you click on something on their site an advertisement pops up. They clearly don't want to give attribution because they want the appearance that it's their content. Nobody wants to buy advertisements on a copied site.

Comment: @CodesInChaos check out the first line in their terms and cond: Intellectual Property

"The Site and its original content, features and functionality are owned by Your Answers. and are protected by international copyright, trademark, patent, trade secret and other intellectual property or proprietary rights laws." Intellectual property? Proprietary? Original Content?!? HA HA HA HA

Comment: I found a similar site the other day.

Comment: It's "_Error 502: Bad gateway_" from CloudFlare right now. Do they have a temporal problems or did you "sort things up" with them really seriously? :>

Comment: @trejder Take that! Ha Ha. I guess I shut 'em down, lol. I did report it here in several places and filed a complaint with google. All they had to do was credit the site and they would have been cool. I wasn't real happy to see my questions and answers up there uncredited, but they included comments and the endings so I saw all the @<username>. Anyway I'm glad it's down.

Comment: @JMFB Mee to, especially, that to use yours / this content legally all one must do is a contribution. No fees, not licenses, no such stuff. They're just lazy or ignorant and got they payment. I don't like putting sites down, but situation like that is an exceptional in my opinion (laziness, ignorance) and should be treated in a special way.

Comment: Just FYI, it looks like it's up again...

Comment: Hmm.. Found another site doing it, when searching on a few of my answers: http://science.manyask.com/viewtopic.php?t=2538316 -- it's a copy of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/why-does-arthur-dent-need-to-bring-a-towel-with-him-in-the-film-version-of-hitc with all the names changed.

Answer (score 20):

Please report these sites to the Stack Exchange powers that be:

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

> Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the form on the contact us page, linked at the bottom of every page.
>
> Use the "Other" reason on the form (fortunately, we don't get enough of these reports to justify making SCRAPERs their own category/reason). Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

Comment: Thank you. I run into these all of the time, and never realized I could report them.

Comment: IIRC, stack employees will contact the site to try and bring them into compliance, and if that fails, take action. As long as they attribute using the correct CC license, what they are doing is allowed.